# Mkr1000 Wifi Configuration

Tags: mkr1000

Is there a package similar to esp8266 WifiManager that supports wifi configuration for Arduino mkr1000?
I have searched everywhere and I got nothing

Comment: https://github.com/khoih-prog/WiFiManager_NINA_Lite

Comment: It shows error "Error compiling for board Arduino MKR1000."

Comment: sorry, I read MKR1010 and you have MKR1000. try to ask Khoi Hoang to make the library WiFi101 compatible. it should be simple.

Answer (score 2):

I'll release a new [**WiFiManager_Generic_Lite**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/WiFiManager_Generic_Lite), with functionality similar to [**WiFiManager_NINA_Lite**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/WiFiManager_NINA_Lite), to provide support specifically to **MKR1000 using WiFi101**, as well as other generic boards (nRF52, SAMD, SAM-DUE, STM32, Teensy, AVR, etc.) using generic WiFi Shields (AT-command, WiFiNINA, etc.) within several days.

Please hold on,

---

---

The new library has just been released : [**WiFiManager_Generic_Lite** in GitHub](https://github.com/khoih-prog/WiFiManager_Generic_Lite) as well as Platform.io [**WiFiManager_Generic_Lite** in PIO](https://platformio.org/lib/show/11761/WiFiManager_Generic_Lite).

The following 2 examples are created specially for you to use and test

1. [MKR1000_WiFi101](https://github.com/khoih-prog/WiFiManager_Generic_Lite/tree/main/examples/MKR1000_WiFi101)
2. [MKR1000_WiFi101_MQTT](https://github.com/khoih-prog/WiFiManager_Generic_Lite/tree/main/examples/MKR1000_WiFi101_MQTT)

Please test and post your feedback here. Post issues, certainly many with this new library, on [**WiFiManager_Generic_Lite issues**](https://github.com/khoih-prog/WiFiManager_Generic_Lite/issues)

Cheers,

Comment: Amazing! please let me know

Comment: Please check the just released library in the answer.